# InApp purchase work on TestFlight but when downloaded from AppStrore

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

After a 2 weeks period of beta testing with TestFlight, I have successfully published my app to AppStore today.

After re-downloading from AppStore, in-app purchase products are not loading anymore.

I am using 'react-native-in-app-utils': https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils

```
InAppUtils.loadProducts(productsIdentifiers, (error, products) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`Error loading produces! ${products}`);
            } else {
                InAppPurchaseIOS._productsLoaded(products);
            }
        });
```

(I know the products are not loading by the UI error)

Did anyone face the same issue? How is it possible to work on TestFlight and not on AppStore?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

4 hours after the app was published, In-app purchase products became available.